# systemctl status log output

Tags: debian, bash, systemd

When I run systemctl status with multiple services at once like

```
sudo systemctl status myservice1 myservice2 myservice3
```

I see the output, but in the end I see

```
lines 1-48/48 (END)
```

or if the output is even larger with more arguments

```
lines 1-62
```

and I can scroll or paginate the output and quit with ***q***.

Can this behaviour be changed that all log output is printed at once and the command exits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
systemctl -l --no-pager status <serviceName>
```

`-l`, `--full`: Do not ellipsize unit names, process tree entries, journal output, or truncate unit descriptions in the output of status, list-units, list-jobs, and list-timers.

Also, show installation targets in the output of is-enabled.
`--no-pager`: Do not pipe output into a pager.

Comment: As a lazy hack, you can avoid a pager by piping through `cat`, like `systemctl -l status <serviceName1> <serviceName2> <serviceName3> | cat`

Answer (score 2):

I was searching this on internet and found the solution here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356753/bash-always-outputs-to-less-how-can-i-turn-this-off

Simply add this to **/etc/profile**:

```
export SYSTEMD_PAGER=cat
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429961/282849

You will also need to modify your sudoers file:

```
 Defaults        env_keep += "SYSTEMD_PAGER"
```